# JPA Select - Some specific keys are slow?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, playframework

Using Play Framwork 1.x - I've made this model definition:

```
@Entity
public class ShareHistoryResult extends GenericModel {
  @Id
  @Index(name = "isinOnly")
  public String ISIN;
  @Id
  @Index(name = "calDate")
  public Date    calDate;
  public Double  opening;
  public Double  closing;
  public Double  highest;
  public Double  lowest;
  public Integer count;
  public Double  turnover;
```

To get the most recent result before a certain date, I'm selecting:

```
ShareHistoryResult shareDay = ShareHistoryResult.find("calDate <= ? AND ISIN = ? AND closing > 0 ORDER BY calDate DESC", date, isin).first();
```

Works fine.

For most isin keys the request takes less than 50ms. But for a few keys (the same every time) it takes as long as 300-400 ms.

The SQL generated by JPA:

```
select sharehisto0_.calDate as calDate9_, sharehisto0_.ISIN as ISIN9_, sharehisto0_.closing as closing9_, sharehisto0_.count as count9_, sharehisto0_.highest as highest9_, sharehisto0_.lowest as lowest9_, sharehisto0_.opening as opening9_, sharehisto0_.turnover as turnover9_ from ShareHistoryResult sharehisto0_ where sharehisto0_.calDate<=? and sharehisto0_.ISIN=? and sharehisto0_.closing>0 order by sharehisto0_.calDate DESC limit ?
```

If I run this SQL directly in MySqlWorkbench with one of the slow keys. It evaulates in a lightning speed of 0.02 - 0.2 sec.

This is the create statement of the table (copied from MySqlWorkbench):

```
CREATE TABLE `ShareHistoryResult` (
  `calDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ISIN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `closing` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `highest` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lowest` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `opening` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `turnover` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`calDate`,`ISIN`),
  KEY `calDate` (`calDate`),
  KEY `isinOnly` (`ISIN`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET
```

Any idees why some keys are remarkably slower than others?

Comment: Did you have the same behavior with the hsql in memory database?

Comment: Can't tell. It's a rather big table so I never tested in memory db.

Comment: If you run the query without first() what are the result sizes? Is there also a difference if you run the query without ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem is that I select all records ordered by date. If I instead limit the date by e.g. calDate <= ? AND calDate > ? (= where parameter 2 is a couple of days before parameter 1) then it evaluates very fast.

I thought that .first() would eliminated the need to range the date, but no.